# Get HTTPRequest in HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Due to project requirement I have created a HttpSessionListener in my spring based application.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
         //some business logic
    }
}
```

I need to set some parameters in request in this class but I am not able to find any way to get http request object in this class. Is there any way to get the http request object here? If no what is the other way too implement it?

Comment: You cannot as that is only for the session. What do you need to set and why? Why would this help on session creation if you need to set request attributes (you cannot set parameters!).

Comment: I am generating a token for avoiding duplicate submission of pages. But due to application legacy design we have to put these tokes in request. Putting in session will not work.

Comment: You cannot put parameters in a request, you can add attributes. If you want the request use a requestlistener, not a sessionlistener.

Comment: You can have several request for the same user session.  So, you cannot bind the session to one single request. As highlighted by @M.Deinum, use requestListener instead.